# Transfer Exodus Wallet to Mist

Tags: mist, import

How do I transfer my Exodus wallet to Mist? I have some Eth based tokens (DRP) and I'd like to be able to see them, but they don't show up in Exodus. I'm baffled by the import function or opening GETH (it wants me to make some contract.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't used Exodus, but generally -- attempt to locate the keystore file (starting with `UTC--`) for upload or use your private key/mnemonic to open the wallet on e.g. [MyEtherWallet](https://www.myetherwallet.com/) (under "Send Ether & Tokens").

Comment: Thanks.okay, I imported the 2 keystore files - one for my ETH and one for my ECR20 token (DRP). MIST imported them, but I don't see the coins. Still waiting on the sync - it'll never happen with my internet. Should I just bag MIST and get myetherwallet? Exodus won't show ETH based coins, only ETH itself.

Comment: @misterkel yeah. MEW requires zero sync.